# What is the set of all $x\in \mathbb{R}^k$ whose coordinates are integral multiples of $2^{-n}$?

Tags: real-analysis

I saw this on Rudin's real and complex analysis. "Let $P_n$ be the set of all $x\in \mathbb{R}^k$ whose coordinates are integral multiples of $2^{-n}$." What is this set? $P_n =\{x\in \mathbb{R}^k: ?\}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be $P_{n}=\{x\in{\bf{R}}^{k}: x=(m_{1}2^{-n},...,m_{k}2^{-n}),~m_{1},...,m_{k}\in{\bf{Z}}\}$.